# How and why do the characters speak Japanese?

Tags: the-devil-is-a-part-timer

In Ente Isla they have their own language, and I don't think the people there (especially the ones living on the land) know anything about Japan or Earth. So how could Emilia, her father and that one guy carrying that cart (in the flashback) speak fluent Japanese?

And if they actually know Japanese, why don't they speak it all the time?

Comment: They speak in their own language, but for the sake of convenience for the watcher, they probably record the scene in Japanese/" this world's language" instead of Ente Isla.

Comment: But why is their native language spoken almost everywhere else then? @nhahtdh

Comment: I'm not sure about the rule, but note 1) the language, as shown in the anime, is encrypted English 2) The flashback, iirc, is rather long, and the speech would have to be prepared in English, and the VA would have to act out the scene to convey the emotion of the characters, in the encrypted English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people from Ente Isla do not speak Japanese.
They are simply shown speaking Japanese for the convenience of the audience during the flashback.

The moments where they are shown speaking their own language instead of Japanese are when they are chanting spells, which might not be able to be cast in other languages, or when it is necessary to remind the viewers that they come from a different world.

When Maou and Alciel had just arrived in Japan, they did not know the language, so it is important to demonstrate the language barrier to the audience.

During Emi's flashback, all the parties involved spoke the same language, so there was no need at all to show a language barrier, instead it is easier to make the whole scene in the audience's language.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it convenience > authenticity? I understand that it's easier for the audience to understand the scenes, but universe-wise it's just "stupid".

Comment: The purpose of the animation, the manga and the light novel are to be entertaining and sell or get audience.
For that, convenience for the public is better.

Also, having all flashbacks and otherworld scenes be in a different language would require translation and subtitles, hightening costs.